# PHP cURL is not posting data

Tags: php, curl

recently I've been working on a little project in order to post some information into a login page so I can access my schedule for school easily. Anyways the problem is I'm not able to post the password onto the website or submit the credentials. The only thing that actually works is posting the username. Here is the code:

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init();

    $datafield = '__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwULLTE2OTMyMjE5NzBkZKC3UMzpz2mvo4EH%2FkIAaElJ4cqX&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEdAASUve01SuLnSrJ144bDmbDAY3plgk0YBAefRz3MyBlTcHY2%2BMc6SrnAqio3oCKbxYainihG6d%2FXh3PZm3b5AoMQa2TJXV1d0bJySVXtESf1LAcmqGM%3D&txtUserName=12345678&txtPassword=Password12345&btnLogin=Login';

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://studentportal.eschooldata.com/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fhhs');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $datafield);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://studentportal.eschooldata.com/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fSchedulePrint.aspx');
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    echo $result;
?>
```

I've looked through many threads but I still don't understand the issue. Any help would be appreciated. Also of course those aren't the real credentials.

**Edit:**
So I changed the code to this and I removed the duplicate CURLOPT_URL but now not even the Username is being inputted. Nothing is happening, the page just displays with nothing occuring.

```
<?php
    $ch = curl_init();

    $username = '12345678';
    $password = 'Password12345';

    $datafield = array('txtUserName' => $username, 'txtPassword' => $password);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://studentportal.eschooldata.com/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fhhs');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($datafield));
    curl_exec($ch);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    echo $result;
}
```

?>

Comment: Note that you also have two `CURLOPT_URL` values there

Comment: `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` is supposed to be an associative array, you don't have to manually encode it.

Comment: @Terry the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` can be either a string OR a key-value pairs.

Comment: I removed the second CURLOPT_URL, still it's not working.

Comment: Can you explain the "not working"? It doesn't really help us understand the problem.

Comment: It should be logging into the website and going to the main page after logging in. It's just not actually doing anything but displaying the page. For some reason, it does not post the login information nor does it log in. Not sure what can be causing this problem.

Comment: I still have not managed to get this working after several attempts, anyone got any clue to why this is not working?